# Batch Delete Files From File On Cmd Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a long list of file names in a txt file, which I generated using

```
findstr /M "string here" *.* > c:\files.log
```

The file is about 3mb. Now i want to delete all of those files. I tried del < c:\files.log but that doesn't work. What should I use?

Comment: probably belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser

Comment: Batch programming is programming, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch for NT on up supports a FOR loop with special switches

**FOR  /F** seems to fit what you want as it allows input from a file and positional delimiters.

See .. http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

You are looking for something like...

for /F "tokens=*" %%a  in (files.log) DO DELETE "%%a"

Comment: For bonus points OP could pipe his findstr input into the FOR.

Comment: Absolutely.... However, segmenting things into a files allows you to inspect/debug batch files.

Comment: Rob: You can't pipe into for. You'd have to use `for /f %x in ('some command')`. But you can't pipe into it :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (filelist.txt) do del %a
```

Comment: Also "delims=" to only have the End-of-line as a delimiter, for long filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Cygwin or something similar it's just:

```
cat files.log | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have %%a and not %a inside the batch file
%a for cmd